# Rails console stalls, doesn't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `rails c` command is hanging. The server is working fine.

Here's what shows when I terminate (Ctrl+C):

```
rails c
^C/Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `verify_server_version'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:62:in `run'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:42:in `warm_run'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `call'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Development/code/Rails/fares-you-can-use-rails/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/TuzsNewMacBook/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Development/code/Rails/fares-you-can-use-rails/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I've been working on adding Devise Omniauth to my app. I think the last time the console loaded was before I started working on that. I've also added `dotenv-rails` if that makes any difference (it appears to be working fine). Here's my devise initializer:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
    config.mailer_sender = 'xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com'
    config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
    config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'
    require 'devise/orm/active_record'
    config.authentication_keys = [:email]
    config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
    config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
    config.params_authenticatable = true
    config.http_authenticatable = false
    config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
    config.http_authentication_realm = 'Application'
    config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
    config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true
    config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11
    config.reconfirmable = true
    config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
    config.password_length = 6..128
    config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
    config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
    config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]
    config.sign_out_via = :delete
    config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
end
```

And, if it helps, here are my routes.

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'regions/index'
  get 'regions/show'
  resources :deals, param: :slug

  resources :regions, param: :slug, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :deals, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :destroy]
  end

  root to: "deals#index"

  # Omniauth
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }  
  get 'pry', to: 'application#pry'
end
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Try running `$ spring stop` then retry

Comment: That worked, thanks!